# Change searchView threshold

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, searchview, threshold

I have a little problem: I have a searchView which works with the suggestionAdapter. The problem is that the searchView start to display results from 2 characters. I have however set the threshold to 1 in the searchable.xml + in the code but it doesn't works.The magic here is if I set the threshold to 5 it works...

Searchable.xml:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/city_list_search"
    android:hint="@string/city_list_search"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1">
</searchable>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My fragment where I also set the threshold to 1:

```
AutoCompleteTextView search_text = (AutoCompleteTextView) mSearchView.findViewById(mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
    search_text.setThreshold(1);

    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(mSearchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
```

Where I set the custom adapter: (called in : public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText))

```
public void updateSearchResults() {
    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new CityListSearchResultAdapter(root.getContext(), mCursor));
}
```

Comment: Try changing `android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"` to `android:completionThreshold="1"`

Comment: I have already try but in the searchable.xml I can't set this parameter. I also can't set this parameter to the searchView in the layout file. I think this parameter is for AutocompleteTextView...

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you have to declare the searchSuggestAutority in your searchable :

```
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

if you really want to use suggestionsAdapter to provide data, don't call setSuggestionsAdapter  in updateSearchResults but in onCreate, just update your cursor.
You can also have a look to https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5514856

Answer (score -1):

You can use Appcompact activity with v7 Searchview. Use as follows to change the threshold,

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0);
```